# App Store must be built with the iOS 15 SDK or later, included in Xcode 13 or later

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

**ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 14.4 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 15 SDK or later, included in Xcode 13 or later**."

In my case, I have a **Mid 2012 MacBook Pro** .. so max support Xcode **version 12.x** and
Mac OS Catalina. SO cannot install Xcode 13.x

If there's a way to run a build on XCode 12, that has the iOS Deployment Target set to 15 - that would be greatly appreciated. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to build with Xcode 13.  A cloud build service may be an option.

Comment: Thanks @paulw11

BUT My system is not supported for xcode 13 so any other solution with code 12.x?

Comment: No. I know it is difficult, but you are using a 10 year old computer.  You either need to upgrade to a machine that can run Xcode 13 or, as I suggested, look at cloud-based build solutions

Answer (score 3):

We also recently got this message from Apple, which is quite an issue for us as our build nodes were not capable of running Xcode 13, and further their own previous posts on the issue only suggested that in order to upload to the App Store apps were required to be built with Xcode 13 after Apr 25, *not* that they also required linking against the iOS 15 SDK, or that apps already uploaded to the app store before the deadline would require this to be approved for release.
We're half way through upgrading our build machines to run a version of MacOS that supports Xcode 13 (causing various issues with other parts of our build of course), installing Xcode 13, and now we have to work out how to upgrade our Xcode project to use the iOS 15 SDK without it breaking even more stuff (actually, initial investigation suggests we don't need to change our project settings at all, it will happen automatically). Happy days, but that's Apple for you (in contrast, most of our MS-stack-based and Android-based applications are using quite old and in some cases out-of-LTS versions of various libraries and build tools, as we haven't had the resources to upgrade yet, but certainly haven't any issues with publishing or running them).

Comment: BTW we had Apple accept the app-store submission after rebuilding with Xcode 13.  But then we tried with Xcode 13.3, and found out it has a bug that causes it to abort with out of memory errors when bitcode generation is on.  In general upgrading our build nodes to Monterey has been a nightmare, lots of changes around JDKs, python availability, default grep behaviour etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=2t1chhp3

Check your iOS SDK version using command

```
xcodebuild -showsdks
```

and xcode version with command

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
```

If your xcode is less than 13 and iOS Sdk less than 15 - you need to update it.
By the way, here is a useful link, it will help you with dependencies https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. I was up-to-date with my iOS, but the Xcode version was an older version and the App Store didn't prompt me for updating Xcode at all, no matter what I tried.

It seems that for some iOS versions you have to manually download Xcode from the Apple Developer portal.

You can alternatively use this link [Xcode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com/) to see what's the latest Xcode version compatible with the iOS installed on your device.