# All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 15 SDK or later, but our iOS SDK is already of version 15.2

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, app-store-connect

I have found similar questions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72096389/app-store-must-be-built-with-the-ios-15-sdk-or-later-included-in-xcode-13-or-la) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72096410/sdk-version-issue-this-app-was-built-with-the-ios-14-5-sdk) articles, but neither can solve my problem.

The message given by Apple Store Connect was also "ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 14.4 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 15 SDK or later, included in Xcode 13 or later."

However, I have checked that I am using xcode 13.2.1 which works with iOS 15.2 SDK, running on macOS Big Sur 11.6.4 (well.... a 2015 iMac, kind of old though). I believe it is capable of building a project with iOS 15.2 SDK, but I just can't find where I shall tune (if necessary) to avoid it keeping using iOS 14.4 SDK to build my project. Could you please help me solve the issue? Thank you very much!!

The figures below show the environment I mentioned above:
[image][image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was an embarrassing reason which caused the problem I raised above. I think I am responsible for showing what was going on to all who have read this post, and especially to those who had paused to think about this issue.

In short, Xcode 13.2.1 does build the app using iOS 15.2 SDK.[image]

I was able to successfully archive, verify in Xcode, and uploaded the binary to app store connect. However, I was not familiar with the app store connect and did not aware that there was another binary built with iOS 14.4 SDK which was left by my predecessor.[image]

Though I tried several times rebuild and re-upload, I kept falsely submitting the old binary to Apple's reviewer.[image]

That's it, and no bug or secret about Xcode using older version of iOS SDK to build apps, it is just not true. Xcode does build using its latest SDK. Again my apologies to those who also worried about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have multiple Xcodes installed, please make sure you have selected the correct version for your Command Line Tools
[image]

Comment: I have checked the preference settings you mentioned above, and I am sure it is Xcode 13.2.1 (13C100). The screenshot is appended above. I found later that there was an embarrassing reason which caused the problem I encountered. I will post this later below. Above all, thank you @JIE for reminding me!